# LISP - cannot call function with optional parameter

Tags: function, lisp, optional-parameters

I have this function in LISP with regular parameter and optional paremater n:

```
(defun lastplus (x &optional (n 0)) //default value for n is 0
    ( if (listp x) //if x is a list
        (
            (list (length x) (n)) //return list that contains length(x) and n
        )
        (n) //else return n
    )
)
```

I am trying to use the function in the listener file but it gives me this error:

```
CL-USER 13 : 4 > (lastplus 2 8) 

Error: Undefined function N called with arguments ().
```

I use LispWorks 6.0.1

Do you know why do I get this error?

Comment: `//` is a valid token.  In particular, it does not introduce a comment.  Comments are introduced with `;` or included in `#|` `|#`.

Comment: You are right. I added these "//" only in my question..

Comment: Btw., 'CL-USER 13 : 4 >' means that you are in a debug level. You might want to go back to the top-level. Use the command :top .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
(defun lastplus (x &optional (n 0)) //default value for n is 0
    ( if (listp x) //if x is a list
        (
            (list (length x) (n)) //return list that contains length(x) and n
        )
        (n) //else return n
    )
)
```

Your formatting style is not Lispy.

Adapt to Lisp formatting:

```
(defun lastplus (x &optional (n 0)) ; default value for n is 0
   (if (listp x) ; if x is a list
        ((list (length x) (n))) ; return list that contains length(x) and n
     (n)))
```

You said: `cannot call function with optional parameter`.

Sure you can. The error message did say something else. You can call a function with an optional parameter. The error is inside the function.

The error says: `Error: Undefined function N called with arguments ().`

So you are calling a function called `N`, which does not exist. With no arguments. Like in `(n)`. Check your code - can you find `(n)`?

Now ask yourself:

- *What does a function call look like?*
- Answer: open parenthesis, function, possibly some arguments, closing parenthesis
- *What does `(n)` look like?*
- Answer: it looks like a function call.
- *Is that what you wanted?*
- Certainly not.
- *What did you want?*
- The variable value.
- *What does that look like?*
- just `n`.
- *Are there other errors?*
- Hmm.
- *What about the form on the third line?*
- That looks wrong, too.
- *It's wrong, too. Same error.*.

Comment: impressive.. you can be a poem writer.. now I see my error..I had to write only n...thanks dude

Comment: Unfortunately, it still gives the same error also after I changed every ocurrence of "(n)" to n..what is the problem now? thanks

Comment: @זאבי כהן: then add this new version of your code to your question and we will look again.

Comment: @זאבי כהן: I don't see a problem in the changed code. How does the error occur?